# What does Linux do when it runs a .deb file?

Tags: linux, debian

I would like to understand what Linux does when it runs a .deb file. What I mean by this is
are there any specific files it will look for or a default name of a file within the .deb file.
I'm quite new to Linux so a simple, straight to the point answer would be great!
Thank you in advance!

Comment: `man dpkg`, section `ACTIONS`, flag `-i` documents this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `.deb` file is an archive (extract it via `ar x package.deb` or just list contents via `dpkg -c package.deb`) with the following contents: `data.tar.xz`, `control.tar.gz`, `debian-binary`

**data.tar.xz**

Extract this archive via `tar -xvf data.tar.xz` and you will have the actual files in the folder structure where they will be installed. All programs are already compiled (in contrast to downloading source code and compiling it yourself).
Say contents for a small package are `./usr/bin/program` (the binary) and `./usr/lib/program/special.so` (a library the program uses), then what is done during installation is just copying these files in the `/usr` directory.

**control.tar.gz**

Extract via `tar -xzvf control.tar.gz`. Contains references for controlling the installation: hash values for safety reasons, exact description of the package version and versions of each file, information regarding dependencies and what files are used for configurations.

The need for describing version and dependencies is obvious. File versions are interesting, as even with installing updates via `.deb`-files e.g. some library files might be the same - so reinstalling them is not needed. Config files on the other hand usually had been adapted by the user, so overwriting them is a no-go.

**debian-binary**

Just tells the system what `.deb`-file standard is used. 2.0 - nowadays.

**What else is happening?**

With the version information `dpkg` updates its logs of installed packages and where to find them. Needed for version and dependency checks as well as when removing packages.

Answer (score 3):

Linux does not run a .deb file directly. If you click on a .deb file and it installs is that so, because the system knows that it should open the .deb file with a program that can install the application(s) packaged in a .deb file. Typically, such a program would be `dpkg`. `dpkg` opens a .deb file and unzips the contents. .deb file contains two zipped archives, etc. (https://fileinfo.com/extension/deb, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deb_(file_format)). One contains instructions/scripts for installation, and other contains actual files for the applications that are installed. Usually the installation script copies the programs to designated directories and sets up some other settings that a program might need. If a program is very simple there are no needed setting, so the installation will just copy the program to its destination, from where you can start it.